# How do you test your emberjs routes?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

After a few months without looking at emberjs, I'm trying to go back into it now, and I'm therefore trying the new router. And I would like to test my routes.

Has anybody tried to write some routing tests with emberjs ?

Let's suppose the very basic following router :

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  root: Ember.Route.extend({
    index: Ember.Route.extend({
      route: '/',
      connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({name: 'home'});
      }
    })
  })
})
```

How do you test that loading the `root.index` route properly loads the `HomeView` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how Ember has already tested the connectOutlet for you:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-views/tests/system/controller_test.js

```
test("connectOutlet instantiates a view, controller, and connects them", function() {
  var postController = Ember.Controller.create();

  var appController = TestApp.ApplicationController.create({
    controllers: { postController: postController },
    namespace: { PostView: TestApp.PostView }
  });
  var view = appController.connectOutlet('post');

  ok(view instanceof TestApp.PostView, "the view is an instance of PostView");
  equal(view.get('controller'), postController, "the controller is looked up on the parent's controllers hash");
  equal(appController.get('view'), view, "the app controller's view is set");
});
```

Other routing related tests can be found at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-routing/tests

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get the name of a view from it's instance.
What I want to check it that the appropriate view is rendered. Not just something.

Comment: view instanceof TestApp.PostView shows that the view is an instance of PostView, for rest of the details of the view you can directly check with the variable view. What do you exactly mean by "get the name of a view from it's instance"

Comment: the `instanceof` is exactly what I was looking for ! \o/ :)

Answer (score 12):

Here is the full test, using [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/) & [Sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) :

code:

```
describe("Given the Router", function(){

    var router = null;

    beforeEach(function(){
        router = Router.create();
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        router = null;
    });

    it("Should be defined", function(){
        expect(router).toBeDefined();
    });

    it("Should have an root route", function(){
        expect(router.get("root")).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe("its root route", function(){
        var root = null;
        beforeEach(function(){
            root = router.get("root").create();
        });

        afterEach(function(){
            root = null;
        });

        it("should have an index route", function(){
            expect(root.get("index")).toBeDefined();
        });

        describe("its index route", function(){
            var indexRoute = null;
            beforeEach(function(){
                indexRoute = root.get("index").create();
            });

            it ("should have route of /", function(){
                expect(indexRoute.get("route")).toEqual("/");
            });

            it ("should connect the outlets to home", function(){

                var fakeRouter = Em.Object.create({applicationController: {connectOutlet: function(){} } });

                var connectOutletSpy = sinon.spy(fakeRouter.applicationController, "connectOutlet");

                var methodCall = connectOutletSpy.withArgs({name:"home"});

                indexRoute.connectOutlets(fakeRouter);

                expect(methodCall.calledOnce).toBeTruthy();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, but checking that the route is defined isn't enough. I need to check that the appropriate view is rendered when the route is loaded.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with the full test code. Basically, you just want to test that your route is calling the "connectOutlet" function with the right args, what happens next is Ember responsibility. If you're unit testing, you want to test in isolation as much as possible, meaning isolation from other components other than your Route.